# Calculate two angles difference (3d game)

Tags: vb.net, math, geometry, angle

I want to record speed of angle movement in a 3D game.
So we have the X axis, where we move from 0-360 with no border, when we are on 359 and move further we hit 0 again.

The game stores the 0-360 in -180-180 instead of 0-360
To calculate the speed I have to record two stages and compare there difference with the time it took, to get the movement speed.

But how do I get the difference.
the difference from 80-120 is = 40 we can just calculate by minusing them.
but the difference from -175 to 175 is = 10, but how do I calculate that? Cause minus them will give -180, but the difference is actually 10.

Comment: Since when is the difference between -175 and 5 going to be 10?  The difference between -5 and 5 is 10 and the difference between -175 and 175 is 10 but the difference between -175 and 5 is 180.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that's also what I meaned. It all just confuses me so much, so my head can't think straight right now xD I ediited my post

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 180 to each value and then take the absolute value of the difference.

```
Dim delta = Math.Abs((180 + final) - (180 + initial))
```

EDIT: Not sure whether you always want positive values and you want to differentiate between the direction, e.g. if the movement is 270 degrees in one direction is that actually 90 degrees in the other direction.  I think that you actually need to define the problem a bit more clearly because it's open to interpretation at the moment.

Comment: I want it as a posetive difference.
Your example does not work for me. I tryed this:
Dim delta = Math.Abs((180 + -175) - (180 + 175)) 
it gives 350, when it actually is 10 I want

I always tryed this: (-175 - 175) Mod 360 which gives 350 too.
But on google when I do it with: (-175 - 175) % 360
it gives 10 as I want....

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a little trigonometry.  I'm not entirely sure what the VB way of doing this is, so I'll just use pseudocode.  If you assume `a1=175` and `a2=-175`, this should work.

```
θ1 ← a1 * π / 180
θ2 ← a2 * π / 180
δ ← acos( cos(θ1)*cos(θ2) + sin(θ1)*sin(θ2) ) * 180 / π
```

If you are averse to the use of the trigonometry, you can use some conditionals instead

```
if a1 < 0 then
    θ1 ← 360 - ((-a1) mod 360)
else
    θ1 ← a1 mod 360

if a2 < 0 then
    θ2 ← 360 - ((-a2) mod 360)
else
    θ2 ← a2 mod 360

δ ← ( MAX(θ1, θ2) - MIN(θ1, θ2) ) mod 360
if δ > 180 then
    δ ← 360 - δ
```

Both of these will return `δ` the smallest angle between the two angles (i.e. it will be in the range `[0, 180]`).  You'll probably get better performance with the second method though there may be some edge cases you also need to check.

Answer (score 0):

`angle1` and `angle2` are in the range `-179...180` and the difference should return the smallest in absolute value among the numbers

```
(angle2-angle1)+k*360
```

where k varies over the integers. So to the difference (175-(-175))=350 some other associated candidates are -730, -370, -10, 710. Obviously, the sought after result would be -10.

The range of the difference in the first term in general is -359...359, so to get a result without sign indefiniteness, in a first step add 360+180=540 and compute the now guaranteed positive remainder mod 360

```
diff = (angle2-angle1+540) mod 360
```

The inserted 360 cancels under the mod operation, the 180 gives a shift of +180 that must be removed in the final result

```
diff = diff - 180
```

is now in the range -180...180 as required.

---

In the example, this calculates as

```
diff = (175-(-175)+540) % 360 - 180
     =  890 % 360 -180
     =  170 - 180
     =  -10
```

as required.

The other way around, exchanging 175 and -175,

```
diff = (-175-175+540) % 360 - 180
     = (-350+540) % 360 - 180
     = 190 % 360 - 180
     = 190 - 180
     = 10
```

Comment: You never defined the meaning of the `k` term in your first equation.  Where does that come from?

Comment: Added it, `k` is any integer, going once (or twice) around the circle by 360° (or the other way around by -360°) does not change the geometric angle, only the number for it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution:

```
Private Function Calcdif(ByVal firstAngle As Single, ByVal secondAngle As Single) As Single
    Dim difference As Single = secondAngle - firstAngle
    Select Case difference
        Case Is < -180
            difference += 360
        Case Is > 180
            difference -= 360
    End Select
    If secondAngle = firstAngle Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return (Math.Abs(difference))
    End If
    End
End Function
```